How do I generate a new SHA-1?
I am new in Flutterflow and in Firebase> Project Settings> General, in my Android app says that I have a problem in my SHA-1, it says "Another project contains an OAuth 2.0 client that uses this same SHA-1 fingerprint and package name combination", I have another iOS app and Web App, but I don't see the SHA-1, I don't know if they are the same, but those do not mark error, will it be possible to get another SHA-1 and replace the wrong one from my Android App? How do I solve this? I don't see it duplicated
I read the help provided by Firebase, but I didn't find anything very useful, I tried to rename my package name in Flutterflow and add it as a new Android app in Firebase console in my project, but I do not know the steps very well so I went back, I do not know how serious the problem is, I am very beginner (maybe it's too obvious), someone could help me? I didn't find a tutorial on Youtube about my problem. So please if you know how can I solve this, tell me. Thanks
